Size of tar ball compared to size of unpacked data
I have a bunch of tar balls of sizes from 1 GB to several 100 GB. The size of the tar ball (uncompressed) was 2.32% to 2.38% larger than the unpacked data. Thus, the difference was a few GB for the larger files. This was quite constant relative difference independent of whether the overall file size was 1 GB or 100 GB.
The file header does not seem to cause this because it is much smaller than the observed difference and the number of files (10 to a few 100) had nearly any impact on this ratio.
What causes this relative increase of the size of the tar balls?
I am not asking about why there is a size difference but why is there a relativ size difference.
edit 2024-11-04: Question is solved. Stupid error from my side. Originally, I only wanted to check whether the order of magnitude of the tar ball size matches the size of the unpacked files and -- in my bash script -- simply appended 000 to the size in kB returned by du. Some weeks later, I used this script for comparing the sizes in detail without modifying the script ... .

Without more information about the nature of the files it's really hard to say. In general I tend to believe that what you see is just a happy coincidence and not a constant rule.
Did you take into consideration that each file in the tar has a header that has the file metadata, including the file location?
So, for example, if each file has a very long path, and the files themselves are small, it can create the described "phenomenon".
Here is an example of what I mean:
I create a folder with a long name and inside it I create 10 files:
mkdir folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer
for i in {1..10}; do head -c 40960 </dev/zero > folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer/"file_$i"; done

And let's tar the folder:
tar -cf f-long.tar folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer    


Now, let's observe the sizes using du -sh ./*
408K    ./f-long.tar
400K    ./folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer

Here we are at that ~2% increased size you saw.
So now, I will create inside folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer a bunch of folders with 100-character long names using:
base_dir="."; for i in {1..8}; do base_dir="$base_dir/$(printf 'a%.0s' {1..100})"; mkdir -p "$base_dir"; done

... and I will move all the files I created in the beginning into the deepest folder. I will tar the folder again:
tar -cf f-longer.tar folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer 

Finally, let's check the output of du again:
408K    ./f-long.tar
436K    ./f-longer.tar
400K    ./folder-with-pretty-long-name-lets-add-more-chars-here-to-make-it-even-longer

So the f-longer.tar is now almost 10% larger than the original folder.
Hope it helps to understand what happens in your case ;)
Mind that on my system the block size is 4kb so all sizes are the multiple of it, on other systems the results might be slightly different.

Thanks for the answer and examples. While reading your answer, I realized that a made a quite dump mistake: In the beginning, I only wanted to check whether the order of magnitude of the file size matches and appended 000 to the size in kB returned by du. Later, I used this script for comparing the sizes in detail ... . I would have awarded the bounty to your but due to unplaned absence I missed the deadline. I started a new bounty and will award it to you the next days.

Without having access to your specific files, it's impossible to say definitively.
From the GNU tar specifications v1.35:
"Physically, an archive consists of a series of file entries terminated by an end-of-archive entry".
This implies that a totally standard tarball should only have a relative size difference based on the number of files in the archive.
However, from that same page:
"In addition to entries describing archive members, an archive may contain entries which tar itself uses to store information", using labels as an example of entries that don't contain actual file data.
While looking for information about this, I found this article, which contains:
"let's consider a scenario where we have a tarball that is 1GB in size when compressed, and when extracted, the unpacked data is several 100GB. The size difference between the tarball and the unpacked data is 2.32% to 2.38%."
The numbers line up exactly, but the article is talking about a single 1GB compressed tarball vs the 100GB of uncompressed raw data. If you could give more information about your specific case, it would make giving a definitive answer easier.

The article you linked was created on the same date at which I asked my question. The number are remarkable similar and there is a calculation "0.00232 => 2.32%" -- whereas 0.00232 is 0,232%. I would guess that the article either was wirtten by someone who read my question and had no clue or is IA-generated. Probably it is the latter.


This implies that a totally standard tarball should only have a relative size difference based on the number of files in the archive.

That's what I also extected.
